# Is there any other way to do automized Paypal payments beside the PayOut API

Tags: paypal

Paypal offers the PayOut API to do batch payouts. However, you have to contact support to enable it and they only do it on larger business accounts that are "managed accounts", at least thats what the asian support team told me.

Sad, because my business requires an automated payout to customers now and then.

However, is there another way to do an automized single payment from my (business) paypal account to another?

Comment: You need to write your own api, the web is parse able by his own meaning.  It depend of your tools or knowledge. i would myself surely do this in php bash with maybe a little help of phantomjs and unix tools. It can be done in many ways. But you need to code

Comment: sure coding is not the prob. however doing this over the web user interface is a bit hacky ... basically I searching for another api option or so ...